# Error and warning messages with qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set `intrK1` which is having some observations and 3 variables that is `V1`, `V2`, `V3`. This is my command:

```
qplot(log10(intrK1$V1),intrK1$V3,geom="point",fill=-intrK1$V3,xlab="Addtag(@)",ylab="Count")+geom_point(aes(weights=-intrK1$V2), position="dodge")
```

It is showing an error which I am unable to figure out.

```
Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

In addition: Warning messages:

```
1: In Ops.factor(intrK1$V2) : - not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(intrK1$V2) : - not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: It would be best if you provided a reproducible example or at least show us the structure of your data.

Comment: The warning messages are rather explicit: you cannot use `weights=-intrK1$V2`, because `intrK1$V2` is of type factor. You should probably convert to numeric, e.g `as.numeric(as.character(intrK1$V2))`.